# SQL Indicator for Group Value Order

Tags: sql, case

I have this table:

TABLE1

| STUDENT | TIME | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | D |
| 1 | 2 | A |
| 1 | 3 | B |
| 1 | 4 | C |
| 1 | 5 | A |
| 2 | 1 | C |
| 2 | 2 | A |
| 2 | 3 | A |
| 2 | 4 | C |
| 3 | 1 | A |
| 4 | 1 | F |
| 4 | 2 | C |
| 5 | 1 | C |
| 5 | 1 | A |
| 6 | 1 | A |
| 6 | 1 | C |

I want to look at every student in `Table1` having **any** row with `Class = A`, and show a `FLAG` in the results set to `1` if the `TIME` for the smallest `Class = A` row for the student is less than the `TIME` for the smallest `Class = C` row for the same student (or there's no `Class = C` row at all). Otherwise, show a `0`.

So I would get this result:

| STUDENT | TIME | CLASS | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | D | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | B | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | C | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | C | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | A | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | C | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | C | 1 |

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN MIN(TIME WHERE CLASS = 'A') < MIN(TIME WHERE CLASS = 'C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 as FLAG
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CLASS = 'A'
```

How can I do this:

Comment: Please don't use images for data or code

Comment: And which dabase system are you using

Comment: @NBK SQL: ANSI, i update the images with data

Comment: it's not clear why you're not showing the TIME = 5 row for Student 1.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it was typo, it is fixed now

Comment: Okay. Also, Student 2 has two C rows. Why only show the 1?

Comment: Oh, both the 5 and 6 student rows have equal values for the A and C times, yet one is flagged, the other not? Why is this? Remember: you are **not allowed to depend of any kind of order-on-disk** for SQL results.

Answer (score 0):

There are some parts of the question yet that are not clear, but this will get you close:

```
SELECT tf.*
  , CASE WHEN t.ATime <= t.CTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Flag
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Student, t1.Time ATime, coalesce(t2.Time, t1.Time) CTime
        ,row_number() over (partition by t1.Student order by t1.Time, t2.Time) rn
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t2.Student = t1.Student AND t2.Class='C'
    WHERE t1.Class = 'A'
) t
INNER JOIN Table1 tf
    ON tf.Student = t.Student
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/Kgh7pBuU

The remaining issues:

1. How to handle the extra row for Student 2 and Class C
2. Students 5 and 6 have the same data, but different flags. The only difference is the order shown in the sample, but this ordering is **imaginary**. Databases are free to present rows in *any order they choose*, so you are not allowed to depend on it for query results.